# Limiting Power in a Coil

Tags: driver, current-limiting, coil

I am currently working on a project to make my own coilgun. But a bit unsure of the driver circuit. Typically, a driver circuit will look something like this: Flyback diode and a mosfet being the primary components.

[image]

For and infinite coil the  magnetic field can be calculated by the equation B=μ0nI. So I can increase the magnetic field by either increasing the number of turns or increasing the current. Currently I have a power supply capable of 30v, 5A (starts as a constant voltage source, but if the current limit is reached it will act as a constant current source, up until the voltage limit is hit). I would also like to experiment with different current levels (ie 1A, 3A, etc).

How are the coils usually current limited? Thinking about it, if I look at a motor and its driver circuit (H bridge), it seems to me that the coil is allowed to draw as much current as it wants, which depends on ohms law, Voltage/Resistance of coil. Then the user controls the voltage instead. Am I correct in this assumption? Are there any other things I need to keep in mind when designing this driver?

ie: if I want the coil to run at 1A, and say it has 5hm resistance, I will need to supply it with 5V.

Comment: Why are you using a P-Channel MOSFET? Also that solenoid will always be energized through the body diode, assuming Vin is positive.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany this was just found online, I haven't actually selected a MOSFET yet, I'm just gonna be using my power supply for now, but I will need one later for the Arduino. As for the diode, why would it? As soon as the MOSFET is switched off it VIN no longer has a path to ground, causing the solenoid/coil to dissipate its energy though the diode. Or did I pick a bad example off of the internet?

Comment: Coil guns might be pretty weak in a single stage when the core reaches saturation. So if you are serious, you need to know where L drops say 20% by measuring dI/dt with a differentiator peak and hold , applying a constant voltage with a high power pulse to prevent it from burning up with say 100W peak. after that, L drops like a rock and you are left with just wire resistance. I=V/R or VI = 1kW for example. Proximity sensors are used to cascade stages with the arrow a=f/m such that a = k * I meaning force has a current ratio. Such that it won’t saturate when it exits past and cuts off current

Comment: Coils are allowed to draw full current at dc but their inductance allows the current to be reduced via PWM

Comment: RdsOn must be far less than your wire resistance. And interwinding capacitance causes resonance with a Q factor and PWM reduces the force.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I will cascade the coils later but right now I want to experiment with different coil sizes. So you are saying I need to avoid hitting saturation by keeping the pulse quick enough to prevent the inductance from dropping (and thus the current increases a bunch)?

Comment: T rise time is L/R total to 63% of current limit.  While dI/dt= V/L so it’s hard to explain how to measure a nonlinear inductor with an exponential decaying current but it starts to rise above the exponential. Then there is back EMF with velocity.  It’s basically a linear motor.  But you can test this various ways to record with a locked arrow using an RLC meter with DC current or equivalent.

Comment: "*Also that solenoid will always be energized through the body diode ...*" Spehro's talking about the diode in the P-Channel MOSFET, not the snubber diode. It will always be forward biased so the transistor can not control the current.